# how to write a Postgres user definded type with array

Tags: c, postgresql, user-defined-types

I'm writing a user defined type in Postgres called personname:

```
#define FLXIBLE_ARRAY_MEMBER 0

PG_MODULE_MAGIC;

typedef struct personname{
    int familyLen;
    int givenLen;
    int givenStart;
    char pname[FLXIBLE_ARRAY_MEMBER];
}personname;
```

I write my personname_in and personname_out function roughly like this:

```
PG_FUNCTION_INFO_V1(pname_in);

Datum
pname_in(PG_FUNCTION_ARGS){
    char* str = PG_GETARG_CSTRING(0);
    personname *name;
    ...
    name = (personname*) palloc(sizeof(personname) + strlen(str) + 1);
    name->familyLen = familyNameLen;
    name->givenLen = givenNameLen;
    name->givenStart = givenNameStart;

    strcpy(name->pname, str);

    PG_RETURN_POINTER(name);
}

PG_FUNCTION_INFO_V1(pname_out);

Datum
pname_out(PG_FUNCTION_ARGS){
    personname *name = (personname*) PG_GETARG_POINTER(0);

    char* family = getFamily(name);
    char* given = getGiven(name);
    char* nameStr;   
    nameStr = psprintf("%s,%s", family, given);

    pfree(family);
    pfree(given);

    PG_RETURN_CSTRING(nameStr);
}
```

And my sql is like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION pname_in(cstring)
   RETURNS personname
   AS '_OBJWD_/pname'
   LANGUAGE C IMMUTABLE STRICT;

CREATE FUNCTION pname_out(personname)
   RETURNS cstring
   AS '_OBJWD_/pname'
   LANGUAGE C IMMUTABLE STRICT;

CREATE TYPE personname (
   internallength = 12,
   input = pname_in,
   output = pname_out
);
```

Now my code can correctly respond with `select "NAME" :: personname;`, and when I insert and select, it can correctly access to all arguments in personname except the pname array.

I create a table called users which contains the pname array, when I type select * from users; it shows this:

[image]

However, when I copy and paste my personname_in and personname_out code in another c file, replace palloc with malloc and test it with some input string from terminal, it can print correct pname value.

Could someone please tell me where did I do wrong, or what's the correct way to create a new type in PostgreSQL with array?

Comment: Why do you use  C for that? You can create such a type with plain SQL, no need to write a C extension

Comment: Yes, I write in and out functions in a C file, and I also need some other operator functions so I have to use C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `CREATE TYPE` statement does not fit the code, and the 4-byte `varlena` header is missing.

Qoth the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/sql-createtype.html):

> While the details of the new type's internal representation are only known to the I/O functions and other functions you create to work with the type, there are several properties of the internal representation that must be declared to PostgreSQL. Foremost of these is ***`internallength`***. Base data types can be fixed-length, in which case ***`internallength`*** is a positive integer, or variable-length, indicated by setting ***`internallength`*** to `VARIABLE`. (Internally, this is represented by setting `typlen` to -1.) The internal representation of all variable-length types must start with a 4-byte integer giving the total length of this value of the type. (Note that the length field is often encoded, as described in Section 68.2; it's unwise to access it directly.)

You must define the type with

```
INTERNALLENGTH = VARIABLE
```

and the struct has to start with a 4-byte integer.

I didn't check for others errors.